# root.after(1000, label.destroy()) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to delete all text by using a button.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

def Play():
    global label
    root.after(1000, label.destroy())

label = Label(root, text = "Welcome to ______, Click Play below if you would Like to play! ").grid(row = 15, column = 15, pady = 10, padx = 750)
button = Button(root, text = "PLAY", command = Play).grid(row = 20, column = 15, pady= 100, padx = 100, ipadx=100)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you expected `label` to be the result of `Label(...)`.

But you wrote

> ```
> label = Label(...).grid(...)
> ```

so `label` is actually the return value of `grid(...)`, which apparently is `None`.

You should call `grid` and assign to `label` in two separate statements:

```
label = Label(...)
label.grid(...)
```

The same applies to `button`.